# Is investing in athletes halal?

Tags: halal-haram, hadith

I previously got a job at UpWork, from **finlete.com**. (a website where fans invest in their athletes and in return will get a share percentage of the athlete's future earnings.) I rejected the offer because I thought that's not halal.
Can you guide me?
About finlete: https://vimeo.com/731055421

Also, investing in a child's studies so that he could give it back when he start's earning?

Answer (score -1):

> However, if you conduct an **immediate** transaction among yourselves, then there is no need for you to record it, but call upon witnesses when a deal is finalized. *Let no harm come to the scribe or witnesses. If you do, then you have gravely exceeded ˹your limits˺. Be mindful of Allah, for Allah ˹is the One Who˺ teaches you. And Allah has ˹perfect˺ knowledge of all things.* (2:282)

> Whatever loans you give, ˹only˺ seeking interest at the expense of people’s wealth will not increase with Allah. *But whatever charity you give, ˹only˺ seeking the pleasure of Allah—it is they whose reward will be multiplied.* (30:39)

Here we are told what interest is halal. If we aren't exclusionary and immediate, we help with investment. *I say an investment is consumption until it is proven to deflate.*